# How can we extract the points of lines or degrees of curves of a custom Shape to feeding our custom path?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to find a way or software to calculate the location of points that make a line or the degrees of curves of a custom Shape, I need this data to build my path in Swift or SwiftUI, how we can calculate or extract those information out of a shape?

**Here more info:** for example I have this down shapes in my photoshop or any other graphical software, I need those point and degrees to build Swift version of that Shape, do we have a special software to extract those data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your vectors to illustrator, import them with [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com) and convert your drawing to code

Comment: thanks, illustrator and PaintCode together? or just one of them? do you have experience Affinity as well? can I use Affinity also?

Comment: I have never used Affinity. As long as you can export your drawing as vectors it will probably export to a format that you can import using PaintCode. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hH1tc-JO1j8

Comment: PaintCode seems best software but it is good for companies I am one person, I can not buy just sub! :(